# Plotting time-dependent temperature fluctuation Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to better understand periodic temperature fluctuations (daily and annually) on Earth. Desmos graphing calculator helped visualize it for me, but I would love to try practicing coding which I'm relatively new to. I've done basic graphing using Matplotlib but this is a bit more advanced for me. So, after solving the heat equation, I get:

```
T = T0 + ΔT * e^(-z√ω/2κ) * cos(ωt-z√ω/2κ)
```

where `ΔT`=amplitude of the periodic temperature change, `T0`=average surface temperature, `z`=depth, `ω`=circular frequency (ie 7.27*10^-5 rad/s for daily fluctuations), `κ`=thermal diffusivity.

I only know how to plot basic equations in Python thus far, any tips on how to handle this?

Comment: Are you looking for a line plot or a 3d surface plot? You should look at the matplotlib gallery https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/gallery.html to find an example you can map your problem onto

Comment: For simplicity I think a line plot would be best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps me separate the actual equation as a function, and simply plug the results of the equation in a plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def thermal_equation(t0, delta_t, z, w, k, total_time):
    t = np.linspace(0, total_time, total_time)
    temp = t0 + delta_t*np.exp(-z*w**0.5/2*k)*np.cos(w*t-(z*w**0.5/2*k))
    return t, temp

x, y = thermal_equation(273, 50, 10, 7.27*10e-5, 0.143, 36000)

plt.plot(x, y, label='temperature fluctuation')
plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.ylabel('temperature (K)')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
```

[image: plot from the equation above]

Obviously I used toy values for the sample plot, so feel free to plug in your own values.

Comment: Ok this is closer to what I was aiming for! However, I am hoping for depth(z) on the y-axis and T on the x-axis.

Comment: All you need to do is replace the function generating x and y with a function that takes T as the variable and returns z as the dependent variable. In turn, you need to fix the time. If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer, thanks!